# How does ORM relate classes/attributes to tables/fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm

I'm trying to understand ORM and looking for examples of the following explanation:

**tables map to classes,
rows map to objects,
columns map to object attributes**

I understand that tables map to classes, but terminology of rows mapping to objects and columns mapping to object attributes have me confused.

Comment: Which ORM? "[ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)" stands for "Object-relational mapping" and there are several that are available for Ruby and Rails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here appeared some good answer while i was painting, but still hopes my simple one would help:
(since you've tagged your question with 'rails', I apply rails code)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :first_name, :email
end

puts User.inspect # => class
puts u = User.create(:first_name => 'name', 
                     :email => 'em@il.com') # => object (class instance)
puts u.name # => object's attribute
```

DB:
[image]

Comment: Your paint skills are second to none! All in seriousness, thank you. The visual representation was just what I need

Answer (score 3):

I find actual examples help best.  Try this:

## Ruby and Rails:

### Create the class (Create the table)

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr :length, :width, :finish, :price, :available
end
```

### Create an instance (Insert a row)

```
my_house = House.new(:length => 23, :width => 12, :finish => 'siding', 
:price => '$100,000.00', :available => false)
```

### Get an instance (Select a row)

```
my_house = House.find(1)
puts my_house.length, my_house.width, my_house.price, 
my_house.finish, my_house.available?
```

## SQL:

### Create the table (Create the class)

```
create table house(
length Integer, 
width Integer, 
finish Varchar(255), 
price Text, 
available Boolean)
# Note this is generic SQL, adapt as needed 
# to your implementation - SQLserver, Oracle, mySQL, etc.
```

### Insert a row (Create an instance)

```
insert into house (length,width,finish,price,available)
values            (23, 12, 'siding', '$100,000.00', false)
```

### Select a row (Get an instance)

```
my_house = select * from house where id = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

So, using ActiveRecord as the example, let's say you have a table posts, with columns 'id', 'title', 'date'.  There are 2 rows in the posts table.

```
posts = Post.all
```

posts will be an Array of length 2.  Each object in the array is one of the rows, and is an instance of class Post.

```
posts[0]
```

This is the first object in the array, which is the representation of the first row in the `posts` table.

```
posts[0].title
```

This will return the `title` attribute of the first object, which is the `title` column in the first row of the `posts` table.

Does that help?